# Online Algorithm Implementation for the Median

Tags: descriptive-statistics, estimators, median, online-algorithms

### Context

My question is related to the [binmedian algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.3301.pdf) which is [suggested in this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/is-it-possible-to-accumulate-a-set-of-statistics-that-describes-a-large-number-of/3376#3376) and its implementation [originally in C](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/median/binmedian.c) and [its adaptation in python](https://github.com/riccardo92/binmedian).

My issue with these algorithms is that **they are not truly online** in the way they are implemented: the only thing they do is compute the median in one pass **given the full array** $X = \left[ x_1\; x_2\;\dots\;x_{n-1}\;x_n\right]$. They claim the memory footprint is $O(1)$ but they still require the full array $X$ as input.

### Question

Assume at step $k$ you only know two things: the step number $k$, the value $x_k$ and the estimator at the previous step $\theta_{k-1}$. This happens when $X$ has very large memory footprint (say $n>10^7$) and one only wants to load $X$ in batches of small sizes (here assume batch of size $1$).

What would be a good recurrence relation to get $\theta_k$ from $k$, $x_k$ and $\theta_{k-1}$ ? I do not mind storing auxiliary variables as long as they have a (small) fixed size that does not depend on $n$.

### Related posts

The following posts answer the question quite well:

- [Median of a huge read-once dataset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/346/269787)
- [Algorithm to dynamically monitor quantiles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/346/269787)

The [livestats python package](https://github.com/cxxr/LiveStats) is very close to what I want, but when experimenting with gaussian mixtures I've had strange behaviors.

### Experiments

When plotting the relative error percentage of the estimated median $\theta_k$ to the target $t_k$
$$ \mathrm{perr}(\theta_k, t_k) = 100\cdot\dfrac{\lvert t_k - \theta_k\rvert}{\lvert t_k\rvert}$$
where $t_k$ is computed using the full array $\texttt{np.median}(X)$, I find important variability in the first $10^3$ samples,

[image: first1kgmm]

But the relative error stays below $5\%$ after $10^3$ samples

[image: next10kgmm]

I'll open another question if I encounter problems in my experiments.

Comment: Also related: [Online estimation of quartiles without storing observations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/103258/1352)

Comment: This is helpful, but it's quite disappointing that 10 years later there isn't a clear solution to this problem. I'd be interested in a comparison of different methods.

Comment: The median is not as well behaved as the mean, so I don't think there will *ever* be a "clear" solution...

Comment: This problem has been discussed at length in at least three threads: I suggest that the duplicate *does* contain a clear and truly online solution.